# ¿Como extraer los resultados de dos select enbebidos en un procedimiento "CALL" de mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un procedimiento de mysql el cual me retorna el resultado de dos select que se encuentran enbebidos dentro del mismo. Una de las tablas me imprime detalles y la otra me imprime el resumen. Lo que deseo lograr es obtener los resultados del detalle e imprimirlos en su respectiva tabla y a si mismo obtener los resultados del resumen e imprimirlo en la tabla de resumen. Anexo mi script

```
<?php 
include('conexion.php');
session_start();
$var=$_SESSION['nnombre'];
if($var == null || $var==''){
        error_reporting(0);
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert('No Inicio Sesión');";  
        echo "window.location = 'login.html';";
        echo "</script>"; 
die();
}
$nombre=$_POST['nom'];
$fecha=$_POST['date'];
$format = str_replace("-","",$fecha);
$rest = substr($format, 0, 6);
$nombre=$_POST['nom'];
settype($isla, "string");
switch ($nombre) {
    case 1:
        $isla='BC';
        break;

    case 2:
        $isla='i1';
        break;

    case 3:
        $isla='i2';
        break;

    case 4:
        $isla='i3';
        break;

    case 5:
        $isla='i4';
        break;

    case 6:
        $isla='i5';
        break;

    case 7:
        $isla='i11';
        break;

    case 8:
        $isla='i12';
        break;

    case 9:
        $isla='i13';
        break;

    case 10:
        $isla='i14';
        break;

    case 11:
        $isla='i15';
        break;

    case 12:
        $isla='i16';
        break;

    default:
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert('No selecciono la Isla');";  
        echo "window.location = 'index.php';";
        echo "</script>"; 
        break;
}
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,"CALL `SGbl`.`Sp_RptResultadosBlaster`($format, 'Sol_Blaster_".$isla."','BL_".$rest."_rbt','BL_".$rest."_rbt_CM', 3);");
$array=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

if($array == null){
    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('No se encontraron datos');";  
    echo "window.location = 'index.php';";
    echo "</script>"; 
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Consultas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/tab.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float: right;">
    <input type="button" name="" onclick="location='index.php'" value="Volver a Inicio">
</div>
<center>
    <h1>Consultas a Reporte Blaster</h1>
    <hr>
    <br>
</center>
<center>
<div class="tab">
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <th>ID Campaña</th>
        <th>Capaña</th>
        <th>Fecha de Registro</th>
        <th>Fecha de Inicio</th>
        <th>Fecha Fin</th>
        <th>Hora Inicio</th>
        <th>Hora Fin</th>
        <th>Telefono de Contacto</th>
        <th>ID Credito</th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
        <th>Primer Llamada</th>
        <th>Ultima Llamada</th>
        <th>Llamadas Exitosas</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        while ($renglon=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Id_Campana'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Campana'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Fecha_Registro'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Fecha_Inicio'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Fecha_Fin'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Hora_Inicio'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Hora_Fin'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['CallerId'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Id_Credito'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Telefono'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['PrimerLLamada'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['UltimaLLamada'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['LLamadasExitosas'] . "</td> ";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
<form action="export.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="formato" value="<?php echo $format; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="isla" value="<?php echo $isla; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="mes" value="<?php echo $rest; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="" value="Exportar Excel">
</form>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID Campaña</th>
        <th>Hora Inicio</th>
        <th>Hora Fin</th>
        <th>Primer Llamada</th>
        <th>Ultima Llamada</th>
        <th>Telefono de Contacto</th>
        <th>Total de Creditos</th>
        <th>Total de Telefono</th>
        <th>Llamadas Exitosas</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        /*while ($renglon=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Id_Campana'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Hora_Inicio'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['Hora_Fin'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['PrimerLlamada'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['MAX(UltimaLlamada)'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['CallerId'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['creditos'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['TelsProgramados'] . "</td> ";
            echo "<td>" . $renglon['LlamadasExitosas'] . "</td> ";
            echo "</tr>";
    }   */
    ?>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Hasta ahora, cuando ejecuto ambas tablas, la segunda me imprime los mismos resultados que la primera (los campos en ambos select se llaman igual) en donde coinciden los nombres de las columnas.

Comment: Ya que dices que los campos de ambas tablas se llaman igual, ¿por qué no usas alias para que se llamen diferente? ¿La SP devuelve los datos correctos? ¿El problema por tanto es sólo de nombres duplicados de columnas en las tablas?

Comment: Los campos de la segunda tabla que tienen nombres distintos muestran lo mismo que la primera y los campos que se llaman distino no muestran nada

Comment: No alcanzo a comprender cuál es el problema. Debes revisar en primer lugar si la consulta funciona (en la base de datos) o sea, si arroja los datos deseados. Además, me pregunto por qué no haces un simple `JOIN` entre las dos tablas, quizá ni siquiera necesites una SP para esto. Haz las pruebas de lugar y plantea mejor la pregunta para poder ayudarte.